# mysql count query

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

mysql> `SELECT * FROM consumer1`;

```
Service_ID | Service_Type | consumer_feedback 
-----------------------------------------------
     31      Printer           -1 
     34      Printer            0 
     31      Printer            0 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1 
     34      Printer            1
```

I need a query such that I need **THE COUNT(Service_ID)=2 AS Service_ID is 31 and 34**.  Please help me and give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Service_ID) FROM consumer1
```

- `DISTINCT` will extract all the
  distinct values of the field
  `Service_ID`. In your case it will
  return 31,34
- `COUNT` will count the number of
  number of such values. In
  your case it will return 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct Service_ID) from consumer1;
```

Answer (score -1):

select count(*) from customer1 where Service_ID=31